# Create object with a function or a function that takes an object?

Tags: javascript

In my project, I have to work with a list of complex objects, even nested ones.
For this question, I will replace that with a basic object: `{value: number}`

I have an array of that object, and now I would like to go over the array and check the object's value:

```js
// First way: Using one function:
console.log("Way #1")

// So I have an array like this:
itemArr = [{
  value: 1
}, {
  value: 2
}, {
  value: 3
}, {
  value: 1
}]

// The function is implemented outside of the objects:
const check = (item) => {
  switch (item.value) {
    case 1:
      return "is one"

    case 2:
      return "is two"

    case 3:
      return "is three"
  }
}

itemArr.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(check(item))
})

// Second way
// The function is implemented inside of the object.
console.log("Way #2")
itemArr = [{
  value: 1,
  check: () => "is one"
}, {
  value: 2,
  check: () => "is two"
}, {
  value: 3,
  check: () => "is three"
}, {
  value: 1,
  check: () => "is one" // this way, even if a value is repeated, I have to write the function again.
}]

itemArr.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.check())
})
```

Is there an obviously better choice in general?
Which way is more efficient / has better performance?

Comment: If you're following DRY principles, the first choice is definitely better. In your second case you are storing a separate function for _each_ entry in the array.

Comment: _"go over the array and check the object's value"_ - Why? For every element? Only a sub-set of them? What's the actual result you want to achieve with that? ...

Comment: it seems absurd to me because it derogates from the maintainability rules of the code: the informational data must not be mixed in the algorithmic part

Comment: I think first is the better way of doing it because in that the third party (the one providing data) is not the person who has the access to output what he wants. Our code decides the actions based on his data. Whereas in second, the third party, data provider has the power to take action. Basically it depends on use case.

And ya from memory perspective, you are adding an extra function for each entry, so that is again a overhead.

Comment: @connexo the function is returning, so no need to break, i guess.

Comment: `itemArr.forEach(check)`? Although `.forEach` doesn't return anything, so I don't see the value of using it over `.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is better. The Second way creates a function in memory for every object of the array.

Reference for better [memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) management

But in the real time try to find some generic way so that the things can be done in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

none of them.

it seems absurd to me because it derogates from the maintainability rules of the code: the informational data must not be mixed in the algorithmic part

do that ?

```js
const itemArr = 
  [ { value: 1 } 
  , { value: 2 } 
  , { value: 3 } 
  , { value: 1 } 
  ] 

const check = []
check[3] = 'is three'
check[1] = 'is one'
check[2] = 'is two'
// or : const check = [,'is one','is two','is three' ]
 

itemArr.forEach(({value: x}) => console.log(check[x]))
```

> if you absolutely want to use a function...

```js
const itemArr = 
  [ { value: 1 } 
  , { value: 2 } 
  , { value: 3 } 
  , { value: 1 } 
  ] 

const checkItem = (()=>
  {
  const msg = []
    msg[3] = 'is three'  // in any order you want
    msg[1] = 'is one'
    msg[2] = 'is two'
 
    return (val) => msg[val]
  })()

itemArr.forEach(({value: x}) => console.log(checkItem(x)))
```

Comment: May you add an explanation to this answer?

Comment: @evolutionxbox explanation added